# How to Find 2nd Parent Category of Item?

Tags: woocommerce, categories

I'm using a multiple category structure like:
Each dash (-) represents a subcategory.

```
Home & Living 
-Furniture
--Study room
---Study desk
--Bedroom
---Baby Room
----Baby Chair
-Kitchen
-Dining room
Sport
Garden
...
```

The code below is on the payment page. If the item to be paid is from the Furniture Category (For example, Study desk or Baby Chair), I have to do some action.
However, I'm not sure how to do this. Each term_id can be retrieved individually. However, this doesn't make much sense as you might guess. Because there are nearly 100 categories.
Actually, I'm looking for the parent of the related product Furniture, but I couldn't find how to do it. I would be very happy if anyone can help

```
foreach (WC()->cart->get_cart() as $item_id => $item) {
//$product = new WC_Product($item['product_id']);
$product_cats = wp_get_post_terms($item['product_id'], 'product_cat');
foreach ($product_cats as $cat) {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you are just looking for the parent category for each item in which case you can continue with your code and add a check for the parent ie

```
foreach (WC()->cart->get_cart() as $item_id => $item) {
    $product_cats = wp_get_post_terms($item['product_id'], 'product_cat');
    $parent_cat = '';
    foreach ($product_cats as $cat) {
        if ( $cat->parent == 0 ) {
           // you have found the parent category so you can end the for loop
           $parent_cat = $cat->parent;
           break;
        }
    }
    // do the action you needed to with your parent cat $parent_cat
}
```